# Trying To Retrieve Messages With Clickatell Half Working

Tags: php, sql, clickatell

This is the code I have.  Maybe I have a giant error.  However, the system will put the API ID, the Message ID, and the sender in the database under its own listing.  HOWVER,  now matter what I do I cannot get it to put the callback for the message text.  It doesn't seem to show up and I am wondering where I am going wrong in retrieving that.

Thank you very much.
Maurissa

```
<?php 

//database connection 

$hostname_sCONN = "localhost"; 
$database_sCONN = "XXXXXX";
$username_sCONN = "XXXXX";
$password_sCONN = "XXXXXX"; 
$sCONN = mysql_pconnect($hostname_sCONN, $username_sCONN, $password_sCONN) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR); 



// Declare variables for url string 
//http://www.mysite.com/callback.php?api_id=xxx&apiMsgId=xxx&cliMsgId=xxx&status=xxx&timestamp=xxx&to=xxx&from=xxx&charge=xxx 


//this will pull the query part of the url i.e. api_id=xxx&apiMsgId=xxx&cliMsgId=xxx&status=xxx&timestamp=xxx&to=xxx&from=xxx&charge=xxx 
$url = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; 


//retrieve contents of the url 
$api_id = $_GET['api_id']; 
$from = $_GET['from']; 
$to = $_GET['to']; 
$text = $_GET['text']; 
$dated = $_GET['timestamp']; 
$apiMsgId = trim($_GET['apiMsgId']); 
$status = $_GET['status']; 
$charge = $_GET['charge']; 




mysql_select_db($database_sCONN, $sCONN); 
$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_messages (msgid, apiMsgId, sender, recipient, dated, message) VALUES ('$api_id', '$apiMsgId', '$from', '$to', '$dated', '$text')"; 
$result = mysql_query($sql, $sCONN) or die(mysql_error()); 

mysql_free_result($rsOutbox); 

mysql_select_db($database_sCONN, $sCONN); 
$sql2 = "SELECT value1 FROM fgusers3 WHERE mobile = '".$from."'"; 
$result2 = mysql_query($sql2, $sCONN) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_free_result($rsOutbox); 

$query4 = "SELECT * FROM `$user` ORDER BY id_user DESC 
                    LIMIT 1";

$result4 = mysql_query($query4);
$row4 = mysql_fetch_array($result4);
$balance = $row4['balance'];


$finalbalance = $result2 + $balance;

$sql3 = "INSERT INTO `$user` (`date`, `credit`, `balance`) VALUES ('$today', '$result2', '$finalbalance')"; 
$result3 = mysql_query($sql, $sCONN) or die(mysql_error());

?>
```

Comment: The code you pasted has nothing to do with Clickatell  API  ( HTTP/S , SMPP / SMTP / FTP / XAML/ SOAP or COM) ....  can you re ask your question ... ???

Comment: It has everything to do with the Clickatell API as this is the Clickatell API HTTP Callback script.

Comment: Ok .. So whats the main challenge .. retrieving the response or saving the response to mysql ??? Am asking this because is not really clear where you have issues ???

Comment: It isn't sending to the database the message (or 'text') part of the response.  It is inserting everything else into the database (timestamp, sender, receiver, etc) but all I get is a blank spot in the message.  I don't know if I am calling it wrong or if there is some weird thing I missed.  But I am soon to be hairless!

Comment: lol ... you would not be hairless .. are you sure you are getting black response ??? no error code no content ???

Comment: I am pretty sure.  There is no error code being produced.  It is inserting all the other data.  It is like it doesn't know to send to the database the text.  It updates the subsequent tables with the appropriate amount of money and everything happens all hunky dorey... minus the inserting of text...

Answer (score 0):

If you are not getting any response this are the likely issues .

A. callback is not enabled when you where sending the message

example (Call back can be 1, 2 or 4 )

```
http://api.clickatell.com/http/sendmsg?session_id=xxx&to=xxxx&text=xxxx&callback=3
```

B. Callback URL as not been sent in Clickatell

C. Clickatell IP lockdown

D. Click can't resolve your url

Please checking all the above ... var_dump the output then we can work on how you would updated it to your mysql database

====== Callbank Information ========

0 No message status returned.uses. 002, 003, 011

2 Returns only final statuses of a message. 004, 005, 006, 007, 008, 010, 012

3 Returns both intermediate and final statuses of a message.All except 001

Thanks
:)

Comment: what is the difference between 1,2 or 4.  Because if I use the url and click it it goes to the appropriate place, inserts all the data... bla bla bla... updates the appropriate accounts, and all is peachy.  So I am not sure why when they do the callback it isn't there?

Comment: Login to for Central API account .. can you see your sent message and any message in the Last 10 MT Messages ???  Also go to manage my product -> Select your API -> Am kae sure your callback information is correct

Comment: If I go to the Summary reports in the account, and it shows the URL as this link, which works perfect and updates everything correctly... it just won't do it unless i click that link: http://www.synchronizedmessaging.com/2-way/callback.php?api_id=3353729&from=16023709303&to=15626615872&timestamp=2012-03-26 07:01:31&text=@sync lets see how long this takes.&charset=ISO-8859-1&udh=

Comment: To add to that... I am confused why the link that they say is the callback URL works... but yet it doesn't send me the stuff.  I have the callback set to 3.  Is that what I want?

Comment: It does not send you stuff you want or does not send you any stuff at all .. we need to take this issue one at a time ...  i would show you how to get other stuff later ... for now ... let just work on you getting any kind of response

Comment: i get stuff but it is only a callback for the message sent originally not the messages responded to.  With the callback I get www.synchronizedmessaging.com/callback2.jpg

Comment: If I type in the url though in the detailed report it will put this in the database.  www.synchronizedmessaging.com/callback2.jpg

Comment: Its good you are getting a callback data for you to get response from user you need Two-Way Number Allocation activated with your api .. please confirm this has been done

Comment: Yes.  Basically the only issue now - have figured out most of the kinks (one being that I didn't realize I was setting up HTTP Get in the wrong spot online).  However, I still am not getting the message ID number now that everything is coming in.  Is there a way it is identified for MO messages that I may have errored on?

Comment: If there is any error ... you would not get an OK response ..you can also independently change delivery status with out using callbacks

Answer (score 0):

You have to capture 'text' instead of 'message', the keyword to get the content of the message is text.